# android return all selected images path

Tags: android

good day. I am hoping that anyone can answer this. I will be straight to my question.
How can I get **ALL** the image location of the selected images from image gallery? 
For example if I select three images on the gallery, it should output me like this.

```
[/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image1.jpg, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image2.jpg, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image3.jpg]
```

This is my code to laod the Image Gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 5);
```

and this is my code to get the image link

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
Log.i("Path : ",imgPath);
```

and this is my log

> 11254-11254/com.example.com I/Path : /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20170104_171334.jpg

As you can see only one were return, even I have been selected 3 items

Comment: `How can I get ALL the image location of the selected images from image gallery? `. ??? What does this question have to do with code that only can upload one image?

Comment: Have a look at `data.getClipData()` or someting like that.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Why you don't using RESTful? If you will use JSON + Retrofit, it will be easy way to add something new client-server api, isn't it?

Comment: I think that is not my quest. My question is " how to get all of the images path that i have been selected in gallery?". Example: If i have selected three images in galley it will output me like this: [/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image1.jpg, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image2.jpg, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/image3.jpg], something like that.

Comment: `think that is not my quest`. You should not have talked about uploading images or php to begin with. You should only have asked how to get the uri of all selected images.